# In Python, How Do I Access A Variable Inside A Function Of A Class?

Tags: python-2.7

How to print the value of num from outside the class?

```
class Robot:
    def add(self):
        num = 10
        a = 56
        a = num + a
        print a

obj1 = Robot()
obj1.add()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the value to `self.num` instead of just `num`:

```
class Robot:
    def add(self):
        self.num = 10
        a = 56
        a = self.num + a
        print a

obj1 = Robot()
obj1.add()
print obj1.num #10
```

Comment: is there any other way without using self??

Comment: Why would you want another approach? This is the most pythonic. That said, you can declare it as a global variable outside of the class and then call it without even doing objc1.num, and just do num.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define num as a global variable inside the class function and then call it with num:

```
class Robot:
    def add(self):
        global num
        num = 10
        a = 56
        a = num + a
        print a

obj1 = Robot()
obj1.add()
print num
```